# Bootstrap template with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, append

I wanted to develop a bootstrap template appending html inside javascript. So that my code is below. I couldn't make it work completely. Appreciate if any contributor helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function bootstrap() {
    var row, column,
        numbers = [
                  [3,3,6],
                  [4,4,4],
                  [2,6,4]
                  ];

        row = '<div class="row">';

        for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            $("body").append(row);

            for (j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
            {
                column = '<div class="col-xs-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-sm-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-md-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-lg-' + numbers[i][j] + '><input type="file" id="myResume" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg"></div>';

                $("body").append(column);
            }
            $("body").append('</div>');
        }
 }

 bootstrap();
```

});

Comment: how you want to get help without providing a working example ? refer to How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you may just ignore the question if you don't understand it from the existing code which is probable you haven't see any code before (:. There is an array above and the problem is to creating bootstrap's html dynamically via javascript to be able to able to rewrite each time. It's pretty with almost a couple of lines of codes as Minimal, Complete and Verifiable as 3 other members offered a solution already.

Comment: Oh, so you are very experienced you don't need any help so why are you asking here? lol

Comment: You should see a psychologist.

Comment: You make me laugh, thats not your website you must be polite and follow rules or go ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. It appears that you are adding multiple columns that have multiple inputs, all with the same ID.

```js
let numbers = [
  [3, 3, 6],
  [4, 4, 4],
  [2, 6, 4]
];

let container = document.querySelector('#container');

numbers.forEach(r => {
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  r.forEach(c => {
    let col = document.createElement('div');
    col.classList.add(`col-xs-${c}`);
    col.classList.add(`col-sm-${c}`);
    col.classList.add(`col-ms-${c}`);
    col.classList.add(`col-lg-${c}`);

    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.classList.add('myResume');
    input.accept = '.txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg';

    col.appendChild(input);
    row.appendChild(col);
  });
  container.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Tx Will, your solution is working actually while I don't understand why my solution isn't. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to be a problem:

```
$(document.body).append('' + column + '</div>');
```

You're adding a closing HTML tag onto column when it already has one, which is probably causing issues.

You seem to be trying to add an open tag, then a bunch of HTML, then a close tag - that's not really how jQuery works. You add complete HTML elements instead.

You should also be adding these columns inside the parent div. So I'd suggest something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    const $row= $("<div class='row'></div>");   //create a row element
    for (j = 0; j < numbers[j].length; j++)
    {
        const column = '<div class="col-xs-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-sm-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-md-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-lg-' + numbers[i][j] + '><input type="file" id="myResume" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg"></div>';

        $row.append(column);   //add the column into the row
    }
    $(document.body).append( $row ); //put the row onto the page
}
```

Comment: Thanks but even I edited a bit, I couldn't make either your solution or mine working. Do you have any idea why Jquery doesn't work like this or Can you show me anything you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function bootstrap() {
        var row, column,
            numbers = [
                      [3,3,6],
                      [4,4,4],
                      [2,6,4]
                      ];

            row = '<div class="row">';

            for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
            {
                $("body").append('' + row + '');
                for (j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++)
                {
                    column = '<div class="col-xs-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-sm-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-md-' + numbers[i][j] + 'col-lg-' + numbers[i][j] + '><input type="file" id="myResume" accept=".txt,.doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg"></div>';

                    $("body").append('' + column + '</div>');
                }
            }
     }

     bootstrap();

});
```

Comment: I actually edited a bit as above depending to your solution but still not solved to display in the screen as I experienced.